# Smart Map - setting an icon size

Tags: plugin-smartmap, google-maps

I'm trying to figure out how to set the size of a marker on a map.

```
{% set options = {
  zoom: 6,
  markerOptions: {
    icon: 'https://www.mysite.com/images/map/marker.png',
    scaledSize: 'new google.maps.Size(20,20)'
  },
} %}
```

It pulls in my marker file correctly, but I don't know what the correct option is to make it scale.

It's a 40px square image, but I want it to show at 20px, so it doesn't look like garbage on a retina screen.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Smart Map **v2.4.2**, it is now possible to build more elaborate markers using a nested syntax for the `markerOptions` value. Try something like this...

```
{% set options = {
  zoom: 6,
  markerOptions: {
    icon: {
      url: 'https://www.mysite.com/images/map/marker.png',
      scaledSize: 'new google.maps.Size(20,20)'
    }
  }
} %}
```

Comment: a ha. I hadn't seen the update yet. (I'm on 2.4.1.) Thank you, Lindsey.